# Json class saving a value while containing other default values

Tags: c#, json, class, object, json.net

Hey all I am trying to figure out how to go about saving just one value in my JSON class instead of having to write the whole JSON out again with "**New**". I am using the Newton JSON.Net.

This is my JSON structure:

```
public class GV
{
  public class Data
  {
    [JsonProperty("pathForNESPosters")]
    public static string PathForNESPosters { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pathForSNESPosters")]
    public static string PathForSNESPosters { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pathForSEGAPosters")]
    public static string PathForSEGAPosters { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pathToNESContent")]
    public static string PathToNESContent { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pathToSNESContent")]
    public static string PathToSNESContent { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pathToSEGAContent")]
    public static string PathToSEGAContent { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lastSavedVolume")]
    public static double LastSavedVolume { get; set; }
  }

  public class Root
  {
    public Data data { get; set; }
  }
```

And I have no issues with loading that data from a file into my class:

```
GV.Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GV.Root>(File.ReadAllText(
    currentAssemblyPath + String.Format(@"\Resources\{0}", "dataForLinks.json")
));
```

But I have yet to find anything searching that will let me do one update to an object in the class without wiping it out doing a **New** statement.

What I am wanting to do is something like the following:

```
-Load the json into my class object [Done]
-Save a value thats in my class object [stuck here]
   GV.pathToNESContent = "new value here";
-Save class object (with the one new value) back to the file for which it came from preserving the other original values. [not here yet]
```

When I update just that one class object I am wanting to contain the original values for all the other JSON data I read in from the file.

Anyone have a good example of the above you can share?

**update**

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `GV.Root.pathToNESContent = "new value here";`?

Comment: @Felix technically it would be `PathToNES`.. with an uppercase P, and the instance isn't called `GV.Root` but I knew what you meant! ;)

Comment: @StealthRT `GV.pathToNESContent = "new value here";` - but, class GV doesn't contain a property calls `pathToNESContent` and you've deser'd to an instance called `myDeserializedClasss` so a static access approach using the type names is inappropriate... I think I'd convert GV to a namespace, tbh (not that its related to your problem, its just that you don't seem to need inner classes and they actually seem to be causing confusion)

Comment: @CaiusJard - of course! Just *feels* that there is more to the question...

Comment: @Felix Yeah I would think it would work that way also but it doesn't seem to want to. See updated OP.

Comment: @CaiusJard see updated OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd ditch the inner class structure:

```
namespace GV
{
  public class Data
  {
    [JsonProperty("pathForNESPosters")]
    public string PathForNESPosters { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pathForSNESPosters")]
    public string PathForSNESPosters { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pathForSEGAPosters")]
    public string PathForSEGAPosters { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pathToNESContent")]
    public string PathToNESContent { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pathToSNESContent")]
    public string PathToSNESContent { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pathToSEGAContent")]
    public string PathToSEGAContent { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lastSavedVolume")]
    public double LastSavedVolume { get; set; }
  }

  public class Root
  {
    public Data Data { get; set; }
  }
```

Deser (use Path.Combine to build paths, not string concat):

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GV.Root>(File.ReadAllText(
    Path.Combine(currentAssemblyPath, "Resources", "dataForLinks.json"))
));
```

Edit:

```
x.Data.PathToNESContent = "...";
```

and re-ser

Comment: Using this produced the same results I've been getting. See updated OP.

Comment: I've just noticed you declared all your properties as `static`; don't

Comment: When I change them to non-static I then am unable to access them from other classes/windows.

Comment: Pass them to the other class/window then! You're misunderstanding/abusing static..

Comment: (If you don't know how to pass your deserialized object around ask a separate question)